# Expected Value of a random variable and its Entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable on a set $A\subset \{0,1\}^n$. If I know $EX$, the expected value of $X$, can I bound $H(X)$, where $H$ is the Shannon entropy?

Comment: See Theorem 5.10 in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/entropypost.pdf (and share your findings here!)

Comment: This theorem requires that X=(X1,X2,...,Xn) for Xi independent Bernoulli random variables. This is not my case here. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Can you help me understand why not?

Comment: Say A=\{(1,0,0...),(0,1,0,0...)\} and X is uniform on A. If X=(X1,X2,...,Xn) for Xi independent Bernoulli random variables, then the probability that X=(1,1,0,0,0,...) would be non zero.

Comment: @user354824 why is it an issue if the probability of X=(1,1,0, ...) be non zero ? So you did fix the distribution of X to uniform ?

Comment: @toliveira your theorem bounds H(X) by mean of p, not E(X).

Comment: @user354824, where in your question did you specify that something like X=(1,1,0,0,0,...) cannot occur?

Comment: @toliveira I did not specify it. I gave an example of an X that is not the product of independent Bernoulli random variables, so it does not meat the conditions of the theorem.

Comment: @user354824. I see. A is not $\{0,1\}^n$ but a subset of it.

Comment: @toliveira Yes, sorry if I did not make that clear.